# Can I modify the HTML contents which passing through the Wireguard?

Tags: vpn, wireguard, modulation

I set up a VPN server for my team with Wireguard.

I want my teammate to notice that their networks are over the VPN by showing small icon in the web page which they visit.

Is there any ways to achieve this? - Can I modify the HTML data which is passing by the VPN(Wireguard)?

If not, is there other VPN solution with which I can do that?

Comment: Are you OK with telling your clients to setup the proxy server inside their network configuration for browsers, etc? If so, you could setup a MITM proxy (https://mitmproxy.org/) inside your wireguard network. Thiis is a python server which has a nice scriptable interface that would allow you to do what you wanted and process HTML inbound and outbound.

Comment: Can you modify traffic passing thru WireGuard? Not if the traffic is also encrypted (HTTPS). Even if the traffic is not encrypted, decoding layer 7 traffic is complicated. Modifying Layer 7 traffic is even more complicated. The quick answer is `NO`. Given enough money, time, and resources, anything is possible.